# STAssertTrue is not working as I expect

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, unit-testing

I have these two lines in a unit test.
If I comment out the `STAssertTrue` test, the data gets written to file with no issues and write to file is `YES`.

```
BOOL writeResult = [winePDF writeToFile:wineDocumentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
STAssertTrue((writeResult), @"Didn't write to file");
```

I would expect this test to pass, but it fails. I've tried

```
STAssertEquals(YES, writeResult, @"Didn't write to file");
```

which also failed.

Not done much in unit testing so slapping my forehead in anticipation of your well informed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks correct to me. Are you sure the write is succeeding? Are you sure that winePDF is non-nill?

I would suggest adding this before your first line:

```
STAssertNotNil(winePDF, @"winePDF should not be nil");
```

Comment: Yes, I've checked. If I do the write to file without the assert, the file is created. It seems if the act of checking causes the problem?

Comment: This test is running after the function returns, so if the assert is not behaving you should still see the file. Have you tried logging the return value?

Comment: You might want to add something to your unit test to delete the file before and/or after the test, in case one was left behind by a successful run.

Comment: There are only three variables here (writeResult, winePDF, wineDocumentDirectoryFilename) so just logging those three variables should pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Yes, exactly. At the risk of offending him, this is a problem that basic debugging will solve. But not ours.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code for better option of debugging:

```
if( ! writeResult) {
    STFail(@"Didn't write to file");
}
```

So you will be sure either your test code is not working or your code is having something wrong.

Comment: Would you try to change the code for writing to file as follows:
    
`BOOL writeResult = [winePDF writeToFile:wineDocumentDirectoryFilename atomically:NO];
STAssertTrue((writeResult), @"Didn't write to file");`